# lightning app not visible when community user logins

Tags: lightning, community

I have tried following things:
1.Added forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global"  in main component.
2.Added my tab in administration in all communities.

But still the APP(tab) is not visible while logged in through community user.
Did I missed something here.

Comment: Have you added that tab via community builder?

Comment: App tab is different thing than navigation menu tab...how did you add your  tab as mentioned in 2nd point?

Comment: Hi @Ayub and Pranay , I have created the tab for App, then added in navigation drawer.So it  is visible to administrator and other org users . Further I added the tab  for communities using following process: 1.Setup 2.All Communities 3. Workspace 4.administration.5.Tabs 6.Added tab to selected tabs .7.Saved.   Did I missed something here?

Comment: do you use crm objects like opportunity in your app?

Comment: I got my mistake.I was creating Lightning Tabs instead of Lightning pages for communities.We need to create lightning pages using lightning builder and then add it to navigation drawer and further into selected tabs from all communities.Thank you all